# Plugin tips for my multi-user (mostly private) Wordpress blogsite

Tags: wordpress

At the moment I am looking into the possibility to switch from a custom programmed blogsite (PHP) to a more well known platform like WordPress. But I need some experts to tell me if my wishes are already made possible through plugins. I tried to browse through the plugin database but it's too comprehensive and I hope you can help me out.

At the moment I have a blogsite where people can register and create their blogs. The can choose to 'lock' their blogs for people and search engines. Other people who want to read the blogs for a specific blogger can make a friend request and the blogger has to accept or deny them. After acceptance they can read all of that users blog. They also have to option to comment.

Does a plugin like that already exists?